# Correct printf formats for double numbers in C

Tags: c, printf, double

What's the meaning of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  double bmax = 31.4159265;
  printf("%1.4e\n", bmax);
}
```

What is the meaning of `%1.4e`? I know `%f` for double.

Comment: %e means scientific notation, 1.4 means 1 digit before the decimal point and 4 after. This doesn't require an SO question, really, just look it up.

Comment: did you try doing `man printf`? Try google, the first link you'll see is http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf, why don't you read it once.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah: the `1` is the minimum field width.  In this format, you can't get less than 5 characters generated because the exponent is printed with `e`, a sign, and 2 digits, plus at least one digit before the exponent, so the width is functionally ignored here.  The 4 _does_ mean 4 decimal places.  If you changed the conversion specification to `"[[%10.4e]]\n"`, you'd get `[[3.1416e+01]]` and using `"[[%13.4e]]\n"`, you'd get `[[   3.1416e+01]]`. Note that `%e` formats always print just one digit before the decimal point.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf a simple Google search will return the printf format right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%e specifier is used to print value of float\double in exponential format.
```

So here `%1.4e` will print 1 digit before the decimal point and 4 digits after the decimal point.

So if `bmax=12.242` then the output will be `1.2242e+01`.

Comment: Note that the `1` is the minimum field width.  In this format, you can't get less than 5 characters generated because the exponent is printed with `e`, a sign, and 2 digits, plus at least one digit before the exponent, so the width is functionally ignored here.  The 4 _does_ mean 4 decimal places.  If you changed the conversion specification to `"[[%10.4e]]\n"`, you'd get `[[3.1416e+01]]` and using `"[[%13.4e]]\n"`, you'd get `[[   3.1416e+01]]`. Note that `%e` formats always print just one digit before the decimal point.

Comment: Also, where do the `*`,  `^` and the third digit in the exponent come from?  The C standard says _The exponent always contains at least two digits,
and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent._  So you should be seeing `1.2242e+01` as the output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   Yes ,thank you for correcting me (I just formatted it thus loosing correct format ) .